# netbeans cannot connect to database accdb

Tags: database, ms-access, netbeans

im using netbeans and i cant compile the code at my comptuer, it works at my friends computer

and im using microsoft access 2007 for database
im using windows 7 64 bit
so here is the error
is it driver error or what?

> run: Dec 19, 2012 7:26:55 PM DBConnect  SEVERE: null
>   java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified    at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3072)   at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
>     at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)  at
>   DBConnect.(DBConnect.java:18)   at
>   LoginForm.(LoginForm.java:31)   at
>   MainForm.(MainForm.java:23)     at
>   MainForm$10.run(MainForm.java:265)    at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
>
> Dec 19, 2012 7:26:55 PM DBConnect  SEVERE: null
>   java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified    at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3072)   at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
>     at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)  at
>   DBConnect.(DBConnect.java:18)   at
>   MasterEmployee.(MasterEmployee.java:33)     at
>   MainForm.(MainForm.java:24)     at
>   MainForm$10.run(MainForm.java:265)    at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
>
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at DBConnect.query(DBConnect.java:28)   at
>   MasterEmployee.(MasterEmployee.java:35)     at
>   MainForm.(MainForm.java:24)     at
>   MainForm$10.run(MainForm.java:265)    at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: i did, but it doesnt work, i've try the 64 bti and 32 bit version of it

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit of Java SDK?

Comment: yes i am, im using the 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago, whith a .accdb database. It looks like Java 6 supports .mdb format pretty well but not so well the .accdb file format, or at least it needs to have the MS-Access Data Connectivity Components instaled on windows in order to work.

That can be the cause why it does not compile on your computer and compiles on your friends computer.

Anyway I found this on MSDN an it worked.

```
class MyConnection 
{
  public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception 
  {
   Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
   Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver   (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=*.accdb");
return c;
}
```

You will need to download and install the "MS-Access Data Connectivity Components" from Microsoft website, in order this to work.